# style not applied to SVGIcon in MaterialUI React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a style that I am applying to ActionSearch icon but unfortunately it does not get passed through.

Not sure what I could write more for the question, I think it's pretty simple but while Paper gets styles, the icon component doesn't.

Any idea why this would be the case?

```
import React from 'react';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import ActionSearch from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/search';

const stylePaper = {
  width: 400,
  margin: '40px auto',
  paddingBottom: 10,
  textAlign: 'center',
  display: 'inline-block'
};

const styleIcon = {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 20
};

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Paper zDepth={2} style={stylePaper} >
          <TextField
            hintText="Type in brand, position or industry"
          />
          <IconButton>
            <ActionSearch style={styleIcon} />
          </IconButton>
        </Paper>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is inspector image

[image: ChromeDevTool debug]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the svg icon has been wrapped as an component in this library(material-ui react), I think you can't apply your style object directly. From the official document, I think you may need to pass your style object for the property "iconStyle" in your  component, check here http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/icon-button.

Comment: I think you are right, as soon as I confirm I will edit the answer (adding react-router) :)